# When should I say I apologize and when should I say I am sorry?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, phrase-usage

Is it related with the size of the wrong I did it or with the respect of the person or something else?

I made some researches and I found that :

> - An apology is a formal admission of a wrongdoing. It may or may not be heartfelt .
> - "I am sorry" is usually seen as being a truer admission of regret.

But I did not understand a truer admission of regret?

Comment: Both can be used interchangeably. But apology is more formal than the word sorry.

Comment: An apology _can_ be a mere formality, like 'sending your apologies' for a business meeting (an official notification that you won't be there). If you have offended someone, "I apologise" and "I am sorry" mean the same thing, but some people think that "I am sorry" sounds more sincere.

Comment: As expected, I found a couple of written instances of [*I'm sorry, but I won't apologise.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I%27m+sorry+but+I+won%27t+apologise%22) AND a couple of hits for [*I apologise but I'm not sorry.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I+apologise+but+I%27m+not+sorry%22) To apologise is to ***say*** you're sorry, even though you might not ***feel*** any regret.

Comment: To say **I am sorry** does not imply any personal blame. **I am sorry that your grandmother has died**. To apologise does imply personal culpability or, at least, the culpability of a group that you represent or are associated with.